# normal conda install vs forge install

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, numpy, anaconda

In order to install some libraries, we just use:

```
conda install pandas
```

While in other cases we use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge html5lib
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conda-forge` is just an alternative channel where you can upload to or download packages from. Usually it makes no difference where you download the package from but sometimes `conda-forge` has the latest version.